# Unexpected Title Appears in WebView VC Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiwebview

in my app I have a `UIWebview` for present a videos in it. 
when click on the video, the webview embedded dynamically to full screen. 
my problem is with its title, it have strange title !! like this : 
[image]

my code is :

```
            cell.vedioWebPage.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            let vedioUrlEncodeStr = videosURLArray[indexPath.item].URL.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            let requestURL : NSURL = NSURL(string: vedioUrlEncodeStr)!
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
            cell.vedioWebPage.loadRequest(request)
```

Why that happens and how to remove it ? 
If anyone has encounter the same problem then please help me on these ?

Thanks

Comment: @lukesIvi I update my question, and added my code to it.

Comment: any chance that you named the VC the Playback_Controls_VC in your storyboard?

Comment: @lukesIvi no i don't

Comment: @lukesIvi this controller is opened automatically when the user click on the youtube video on the webview, it's not added on the storyboard.

Comment: Oh I see... Are you using an API? YouTube API?

Comment: @JAL hey, this is my question :)

Comment: Is there more code you can add? This is pretty mind bending. Have you tried printing to the logs ALL of the values? Try that, somewhere it should show that title (hopefully).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97888/discussion-between-lukesivi-and-rawan).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I was never able to figure out what was wrong.

Comment: @JAL No I didn't find anything :( 
If you find any useful things please tell me. Thanks

Comment: @Rawan I see you've added some code to your question, but there isn't enough information to fix your problem.  Can you upload a sample project with the minimum code to show the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The question is to old, but may be anyone will search for the answer, like me...
This bug may appears if you forced app locale. Can be fixed (or changed) by defining PLAYBACK_CONTROLS_VIEW_CONTROLLER_DONE_BUTTON_TITLE string it your Localizable.string file.

[image]